# An object holding small tables vs a larger object holding no tables

Tags: javascript, performance, lua

I asked this question about lua, but it wouldn't be bad to know if javascript or other programming languages are the same.

So, say I have an object:

```
{og = {-200000, -200000, -199200, -200000}, re = {-200000, -200000, -199200, -200000}, GID = 0, isActive = true}
```

Right now it's made so that it holds two tables holding four things each.
My question is, would it be more memory or speed efficient to do it that way, or to have it in a bigger object like this?

```
{ox1=-200000, oy1=-200000, ox2=-199200, oy2=-200000, rx1=-200000, ry1=-200000, rx2=-199200, ry2=-200000, GID = 0, isActive = true}
```

Comment: Not taking into account the memory requirements, the first option is way better in terms of manageability. You can pass vectors around, run some transformations on its data in generic way, extend/shrink/concatenate when needed. Having string names for individual elements (second case) just freezes that data structure, forcing you to write lots of case-specific functions when processing/transforming the data.

Comment: The fastest way is using an array `{[1]=GID, [2]=isActive, [3]=ox1, [4]=oy1, [5]=rx1, [6]=ry1, [7]=ox2, [8]=oy2, [9]=rx2, [10]=ry2, [11]=ox3,...}`. The code would have bad readability/manageability due to using integer indices instead of human-friendly field names.

Comment: @Vlad and Egor Skriptunoff - Thanks, I'll experiment with both.